# Create Paypal Private Key and Public Certificate

Tags: php, paypal

Is it possible to Create a Private Key and Public Certificate via PHP?

Because the amount of the transactions in our shopping cart can be high, and also PayPal is requiring for this in the payment button is to create a Private Key and Public Certificate. These are .pem files and I not have the code to create.

I don't know how to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate the private and public keys using openssl. Check out [this](https://cms.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_encryptedwebpayments#id08A3I0QC0X4) documentation over at Paypal. Follow the steps to set your business account using encrypted payments.

Additionally, there is this [tutorial](http://www.stellarwebsolutions.com/en/articles/paypal_button_encryption_php.php) that I used to generate the encrypted button using the keys that you generated with PHP when I had to setup a checkout page.

Comment: The second link is broken.